# Delay in logwatch sending results as an email

Tags: logwatch

I have set up a dual server email system using Debian. One server is active, the other just syncs all the email data in case of a server failure. Everything is working very well, but I notice a very strange behavior.

The backup server has a logwatch cronjob set up to run at 06:25 AM and send its results to the default user on the active server as an email.

This works, BUT logging on to the active server with a thunderbird email client, I see that it can be as late at 04:30 PM before the email (timestamped 06:25 AM) is received. "Get Messages" selected on the thunderbird client does not seem to get the missing email to the default user's Inbox any quicker. I just have to wait for it to show up.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Look at the logs, and try to find out where the delay is. Is it the logwatch script that takes too long? Is it the local system that repeatedly refuses to accept the message? Is it the remote system that is repeatedly refusing to accept the message? Does the message take too long to get delivered on the remote system after being accepted? Does your DNS return useful results? Does it do that within a reasonable delay? Is the report hitting spam checks? TL; DR: read the logs.